# Prove $\int \frac{1}{cos^n(x)}dx = \frac{1}{n-1}\frac{sin(x)}{cos^{n-1}(x)} + \frac{n-2}{n-1}\int \frac{1}{cos^{n-2}(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to prove, $$\int \frac{1}{cos^n(x)}dx = \frac{1}{n-1}\frac{sin(x)}{cos^{n-1}(x)} + \frac{n-2}{n-1}\int \frac{1}{cos^{n-2}(x)}dx $$

I tried proceeding similar to the case when $cos^n(x)$ is in the numerator, but I am not able to split it into simpler functions to reduce the integral. How should $cos^n(x)$ be split so as to get the right hand side of the equality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Write the numerator as

$$1=\cos^2 (x)+\sin (x).\sin (x ) $$ and integrate by parts using

$$u (x)=\sin (x) $$ and
$$v'(x)=\frac {\sin (x)}{\cos^n (x)} $$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!